# Should i have two links on my Home Page?

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design

I have an important link called 'tlm'. The link has been placed twice on the home page but in different locations. According to Usability Guidelines, two links having sharing similar site navigation is considered bad practice. What should I do? Any suggestions.

Comment: According to what usability guidelines?  There are two 'about' links on the pages of this website, for example.

Comment: you can go through the link for usability guideline; http://www.nngroup.com/articles/113-design-guidelines-homepage-usability/

Comment: @Vipala Where exactly in the article you reference is the guideline to which you are referring?

Comment: Rule 18, and maybe also 42 and 5. That page has many repeated links itself. For example, there is a list of topics on the left, and in the footer, there is a shorter list of popular topics. It's all about context. I only see duplicate links as an issue if it habitually causes any doubt over the difference between them. That is, based on observation, and not some UX analyst's presumptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fine, so long as:

1. The two links share the same name *exactly*, so you don't imply there are two different pages, and
2. The two links are separate (e.g. not in the same navigation menu), so that you don't imply there are two different 'versions' of the same page, or make users going to the menu wonder which one they need to choose.

Answer (score 2):

If this subpage is very important, I don't see a problem doing it like this. The only thing you should to make sure about is that you do not actually double it in **navigation**. In other words, there should be one link to one place in nav (of course it can be doubled in footer nav), but you can put a **box with a link** to this feature to make it more visible and increase click-through rate.

Some examples:

- http://www.deezer.com/ - sign up links
- http://flipboard.com/ - get the app links put in nav and in the body
- https://cheddarapp.com/ - sign up links again: in nav and in body